# gallery intent open the clicked image

Tags: image, click, gallery, default

I have a Grid View which displays images downloaded by user to a folder onto the SD card. The images change and depend on what the user decided to download and save to the Application folder. Now my question is how i open the very image i clicked on using android stock or default gallery. I'm  using the code below. How do i get the image path of the image view i clicked on and use it to open that specific image?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ACTION_VIEW` to `ACTION_PICK`